# Additional Manifest: Warning 81010002

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, manifest

Pasted the following into a exe.manifest file for a VS10 Win32 project from  code found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
<ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
</windowsSettings>
```

Building generated the linker warning:

> warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "longPathAware" in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings".

Understandable, based on the age of the bundled mt.exe as explained in this similar [issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670561).
Question is, will this in any way affect the long path awareness of the application on a platform where the attribute is known?

Comment: It appears there is an issue with the xml code on the [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?) page. Have been [attempting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f63c6ae3-0abf-4b1b-b2eb-9664fcbc0ef5/linker-warning-81010002?forum=visualstudiogeneral) to contact MS. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded the 2.4 Gb W10 SDK, thanks to [Sera's suggestion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f63c6ae3-0abf-4b1b-b2eb-9664fcbc0ef5/linker-warning-81010002?forum=vcgeneral),  and copied the 1 mb file *mt.exe* over to `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`. Warning not generated with the new *mt*. (Minor issues with the Environment variables set for the 7.1 SDK in `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin` added in some extra flavour and texture to the operation)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to disable manifest generation in the projects linker options and manually create an external manifest. It must be named like "YourApplication.exe.manifest" and be located next to "YourApplication.exe".

I had to copy the manifest via post-build event as VS always deleted the manifest when doing a clean build.